# Fail to copy all PostgreSQL databases between servers although there is no error message

Tags: postgresql, migration, psql

I want to copy all databases from *PostgreSQL 9.3* on Server-1 (*Windows 7*) to an empty *PostgreSQL 12.0* on Server-2 (*Windows Server 2012 R2*). The steps are as follows:

1. On Server-1:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin>pg_dumpall.exe -U postgres -W -f fulldump.sql
   ```
2. Copy `fulldump.sql` from Server-1 to Server-2.
3. On Server-2:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql.exe -f fulldump.sql -U postgres
   Password for user postgres:
   ```

No error message appears, all seems to be fine. However, none of the databases appears in *PostgreSQL 12.0* of the new Server-2. Unfortunately, there are to my knowledge no matching questions in this forum where I could draw some hints from. What is missing in my workflow?

Answer (score 1):

The dump-file had a size of 0 Bytes indicating that it was empty. Repeating the dumping process delivered a non-empty file with which the import process with `psql` worked fine.